# Does Consul KV supports reading multiple keys?

Tags: consul, consul-kv

Does Consul KV supports reading multiple keys? Similar to Redis's [MGET](https://redis.io/commands/mget).

Answer (score 0):

You can use KV.Keys and pass in partial key locations, then enumerate the response to get/delete the KVpairs.